# Is there a LESS file for OnsenUI-themes

Tags: onsen-ui

Are there less files to easify creating an own theme? Or is there a repository with custom themes (besides the one shipping with onsenui) available?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own theme from the same repository. it's inside the themes-module directory

https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/tree/master/themes/theme-modules

It uses stylus.

To build it, just cd to themes directory where Gruntfile.js is located. then type

```
 grunt
```